# Calculate the size in pixels of div based on its content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What would be the best way in Javascript/JQuery to determine the size in pixels a div would actually take to display it?

Let say I have a table with and the columns are fixed with the tag width="60px". Inside this column I add dynamically a div with a certain content, which will mostly be the following :

```
<div class="auto">
<img width="50px" src="/images/header-5123724.png">
<hr>
<span>Table1</span></div>
```

So, I know the size of the image which is 50px, but I do not know how long the text will be.
Another hint I have is that the element `<span>` will always be there, and the content should not be wrapped.

Is there a way to "render" the span and to get the size in pixels?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: let the browser render the element then get the size and make adjustments

Comment: you looking for `innerheight` or `innerwidth`?

Comment: I know this, but still my column is cutting my text. The font size could play some role into it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to accomplish what I wanted. I will post it here, maybe that can help somebody.

```
// add an extra span
$(this).parent().append('<span id="test" />');

//.. pick up the element to test into obj

// test the size
$('#test').html(obj.text()).css({
  'font-family': obj.css('font-family'),
  'font-size': obj.css('font-size'),
  'font-weight': obj.css('font-weight')
});

//Width and adjustment
Width = $('#test').width() + 24;

//...If we want to check the max width, then we can loop through many columns of the table

//Finally adjust the width

obj.width(Width).css('min-width', Width);

//Cleanup
$('#test').remove();";
```

It is not very clean, but that worked for my case. For some reason the size of the columns were not set properly because it was resized by some plugin after the content was rendered by the browser.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Will the width be calculated on page load or on the fly?

If it is on page load then, **#cont** is the id of the content box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dynWidth = $('#cont').width();
    console.log('dynWidth: ' + dynWidth);
});
```

If it is on the fly then,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cont').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
        var dynWidth = $('#cont').width();
        console.log('changed dynWidth: ' + dynWidth);
    });
});
```

Note: DOMSubtreeModified is not supported in IE8 (and below).

For any details refer this [link](http://help.dottoro.com/ljrmcldi.php).